# Ability for users to add images to comments in Rails forum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, comments, attachment, forum

So i have added the ability for users to add images to posts in my rails forum. I now want users to be able to add images to comments to posts.
I began with a migration add_attachment_image_to_comments.rb

```
class AddAttachmentImageToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :comments do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :comments, :image
  end
end
```

Edited the view file:

```
= simple_form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f|
  = f.input :comment
  = f.input :image
  %br
  = f.submit
```

Here is the posts_controller file:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 7)
end

def show
end

def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
end

def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end


def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end

private

def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :image)
end
```

end

Here is the comments_controller file:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:comment,     :image))
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    @comment.save

    if @comment.save
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

    if @comment.update(params[:comment].permit(:comment, :image))
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
end
```

This give users the ability to add the attachment. The problem i have now is getting the image to show in the comments section on the post.
This is my show file:

```
#post_content

  %h1= @post.title
  %p= @post.content
  = image_tag @post.image.url(:medium)

  #comments
      %h2
          = @post.comments.count
          Comment(s)
      = render @post.comments
      = image_tag @comment.image.url(:medium)
```

I get the error - undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass. Highlighing this row - = image_tag @comment.image.url(:medium)

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your question with the related controller's action code?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I have now added the comments_controller file.

Comment: What is the name of the view page that has that piece of code?

Comment: the view file is show.html.haml in my app/view/posts.

Comment: Ok. Please paste the `posts_controller` code.

Comment: I have now added the posts_controller file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass

The problem is `@comment` is ***nil*** at this line `= image_tag @comment.image.url(:medium)` because you haven't declared `@comment` in the `show` method of `posts_controller`.

***Solution***

As ***post*** can have many ***comments*** and since `@post` is available, you can iterate through the `@post`'s comments in the view like below.

```
- @post.comments.each do |comment|
= image_tag comment.image.url(:medium)
```